# Subtract two cells based on certain conditions from excel data in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have my data say -

| id | user | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 223 |
| 2 | cde | 676 |
| 3 | efg | 89 |
| 4 | hij | 0 |
| 5 | klm | 33 |

What i need to do is, I will create a measure and then put a dax code. i need to subtract the amount of id 2 and id 5 i.e 676 - 33.
I need to write a dax code in power bi to get the output as 643. Please help me to get my output. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this measure to get desired result

[image]

Comment: BTW!!! i just wanted to ask why using sum('table'[amount]) in the formula?

Comment: CALCULATE function takes expression in first argument so we need to use aggregation SUM